# Active Directory using secured Global Catalog failed

Tags: active-directory

Let me start off by saying I'm fairly new to active directory, and I'm not the one who handles the configurations of the servers (if this is indeed a server related problem). However, if given proper advice I can relay said advice to the correct people.

We're running a large ASP.NET  C# .NET 3.5  application.

Here is the scenerio we're encountering:

I created a test page to test our global catalog AD searches.

From Test server 1 here is what happens:

Using GC://TEST.COM:3268 (unsecured) -> Great performance.

Using G:C//TEST.COM:3269 (secured) -> Great Performance

From Test server 2:

Using GC://TEST.COM:3268 (unsecured) -> Great performance.

Using G:C//TEST.COM:3269 (secured) -> Fails.

The only exception I see is: Exception: "The server is not operational"

I wouldn't think it's a code issue because both test servers are running the same code. We only have an issue when we try to connect to the GC's secure port from Test server 2.

Here is exception information when I try to run it on the server, I have it dumping the exception to a log table:

Directory Services Com Exception (Exception Message) : The server is not operational.
 ErrorCode: -2147016646
 Stacktrace:

at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)

at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind() at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()

at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)

at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindOne()at TestClass.GetUserDomainTest(String UserName) in

testclass.aspx.cs:line 155

Like I said, I don't believe it is a code issue, but I have enclosed the code if it will possilby help:

```
private string GetUserDomain2(string UserName) 
{ 
    string domainName = String.Empty; 
    try 
    { 
       // This is Test page code so we can change the values as we want 
        DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(txtGCPath.Text) 
        entry.Username = txtGCUserID.Text; 
        entry.Password = txtGCPassword.Text; 
        // Set SSL or leave default 
        if (cb1.Checked == true) 
        { 
            entry.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.SecureSocketsLayer; 
        } 

        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(); 
        search.SearchRoot = entry; 
        search.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree; 
        search.Filter = string.Format(txtGCFilter.Text, UserName); 


        SearchResult results = search.FindOne(); // CRASHES HERE 
      // Parsing code removed. 
      return domainName; 
   }
```

Comment: Does the second server have a certificate that's valid? Is AD even listening on 3269?

Comment: @Mohammed did you ever get to the root cause of this? i have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need SSL and SSL ist not enabled by default. You can use Kerberos security features to fully encrypt the traffic. This is what I do with SASL' QOP `auth-conf`.